# What distance apart should Elfa vertical wall brackets be?

Tags: shelving

I would like to install an [Elfa system](https://uk.elfa.com) in a storage room under the stairs, but cannot find out what distance apart the vertical wall brackets should be placed at. I checked the website but could not find out how far apart they should be.

Does anyone know what distance apart the vertical wall brackets should be? I would like to use their shelves/baskets/etc.

https://uk.elfa.com

Answer (score 1):

The best bet it to locate the vertical bracket right over a stud so that they can be fastened into the stud.

For the maximum holding capacity consider one vertical bracket on each stud.

The system that you want to use looks like it is one that has a top rail that the vertical rails hang from. With the top rail it can be fastened into all the studs that it crosses or if high enough on the wall right into the top plate. With this type of system it can still be an advantage to locate the verticals over studs so that they can be anchored to the wall. Otherwise there is the possibility of the lower ends of the verticals swinging back and forth some.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the website under "Customer Service".  In the FAQ section, they recommend that the spacing be no more than 90 cm.  However, complete assembly instructions are also available on the site which you should download.